# How to properly make JavaFX TableView editable in Java 8?

Tags: java, javafx

I want the user to be able to edit a cell containing a String in a Java TableView.
In my controller I have simple:

```
// At beginning of class declaration
@FXML private TableColumn<FormTokens, String> valuColumn;

// Later at initialization
valuColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

When attempting to do the following:

```
valuColumn.setCellValueFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<FormTokens>forTableColumn());
```

I am getting a:

```
Error:(409, 95) java: incompatible types: javafx.util.Callback<javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<sample.FormTokens,java.lang.String>,javafx.scene.control.TableCell<sample.FormTokens,java.lang.String>> cannot be converted to javafx.util.Callback<javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<sample.FormTokens,java.lang.String>,javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue<java.lang.String>>
```

What is the proper way to make it such that a user can click/double click on a cell and modify the contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are calling `setCellFactory(...)`, and not `setCellValueFactory(...)`?

Comment: Does completing the edit commit the edit? or is an additional event handler required?

Comment: IIRC to complete the edit in the `TextFieldTableCell` implementation, the user must press enter. What happens to the data at that point depends a bit on the way your model class (`FormTokens`) is set up.